# Debug stored procedure with user defined data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to debug a stored procedure with a user defined data type as a parameter?

Edit: which is the syntax to call it? (exec ....)

My type:

> ```
> CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FacturaInspeccion] AS TABLE(  
>     [sIdServicio] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,  
>     [nIdTipoInspeccion] [int] NOT NULL,  
>     [sIdTipoMotivoInspeccion] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,  
>     [nIdTipoVehiculo] [int] NOT NULL,  
>     [nBase] [real] NOT NULL,  
>     [nNoPeriodica] [real] NULL,  
>     [nTarifaConProyecto] [real] NULL,  
>     [nTarifaSinyecto] [real] NULL,  
>     [nTasaTrafico] [real] NULL,  
>     [nDescuento] [real] NULL,  
>     [nTotal] [float] NULL
> ```
>
> )
>   GO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realised that it's just a table,so I declared the type, inserted the values and called the stored procedure.

Store procedure declaration:

> CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertarFactura]
>       @tableFacturaInspeccion FacturaInspeccion READONLY,
>       ...

Call to the stored procedure:

> USE [DATABASE]
>   GO
>   DECLARE @return_value int
>
> DECLARE @tablaTmp FacturaInspeccion
>
> INSERT INTO @tablaTmp(sIdServicio,nIdTipoInspeccion,sIdTipoMotivoInspeccion, nIdTipoVehiculo,
>       nBase, nNoPeriodica, nTarifaConProyecto, nTarifaSinyecto, nTasaTrafico, nDescuento, nTotal)
>       VALUES(79, 1, '00', 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 100)
>
> EXEC   @return_value = [dbo].[spInsertarFactura]

And after that, time to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can debug it normally, but you unfortunately don't get a good view on the data in the TVP.

See the following [Microsoft Connect items](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=table%2bvariable%2bdebugger) for more info (and vote if you want to get better support for debugging TVPs ;) ).

Comment: And how can you send the data type in the "exec ..." ?

Comment: If you need to pass a table into a procedure I would suggest looking into passing an XML table to a XML parameter in a procedure.

Comment: @ch3r1f, by declaring a variable of that type (which will give you a table variable), loading data into it, and then pass the variable - nothing special there...

Comment: @Lucero, yes, nothing especial,  take a look to my answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ch3r1f, next time maybe do ask the question in a less misleading way: your question really was "how to manually invoke a SP with table-valued parameters" or so - the issue with debugging (that you cannot easily look into TVP data) is what I addressed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest that you add a debug variable to your input varaibles (with a default of 0) then when you want to test the SP, you set the debug to 1 and you can run queries of the data in test mode. For instnce you could add a line that says

IF @debug = 1 Begin Select * from @tableFacturaInspeccion END

That would allow you see that the data you wnated to have input is what you intended it to be for instnce. Or if you are doing a more complex query with a join as part of ana insert, you could see the select stament in the debuig mode and rollback all inserts while you are figuring out how to get the proc correct. I always include a debug or test variaable in anything complex sp because I will want to be able to look at things at differnt points in time in the proc to debug. And until I know it's right, I want any actions rolled back.